# How do I replace the header and trailer of all files in a directory with a new header and trailer string, but only up to a certain character?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have files in a directory:
ex:

```
file1
file2
```

Both files have contents that look like the below (header, body, trailer words just for reference):

```
header: 123xxx   xxx   value=file1id
body: blah blah blah
trailer: 123zzz   zzz   value=file1id
```

I want to run a linux command that will replace the header and trailer of all the files in the directory, up to "file1id", so that they look like the below:

```
header: 321aaa   aaa   value=file1id
body: blah blah blah
trailer: 321bbb   bbb   value=file1id
```

I can easily find how to replace the whole header or trailer in a file on Google, but I need the file1id in my file. I need some guidance on how to loop through files in a directory and replace the header and trailer up to a certain character in the header and trailer.

I have seen a variety of sed and awk expressions that delete and replace the header or trailer.

```
sed -rne 's/(value=)\s+\w+/\1 yyy/gip'
```

As I mentioned above, I want to run a linux command that will replace the header and trailer of all the files in the directory, up to "file1id", so that they look like the below:

```
header: 321aaa   aaa   value=file1id
body: blah blah blah
trailer: 321bbb   bbb   value=file1id
```

Comment: @John1024 Thank you for editing! I was looking around for the option but could not locate it!!

Comment: You're welcome.  To format code or data, use the `{}` button in the editor (or just indent by 4 spaces).

Comment: Is your goal replacing 'xxx' with 'aaa' and 'zzz' with 'bbb'?

Comment: @John1024 awesome ty, will use that next time!

Comment: @HaiVu not exactly, my goal is to read the file and replace everything in the header up to "value=". Same thing in the trailer, everything up to "value=".

Comment: @HaiVu Actually for my purposes, replacing xxx with aaa and zzz with bbb works, but I will not know what xxx is nor what zzz is. All I know is that they are on the header and trailer and that their length and position do not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed` example has two replace commands, one for the first line (header) and one for last line trailer (denoted by $ in the second substitution). `-i` option of `sed`   edits the file in place.

`sed -i '1 s/^.*value=/yoursubstitution value=/; $ s/^.*value=/yoursubstitution value=/'`

output:

```
yoursubstitution value=file1id
body: blah blah blah
yoursubstitution value=file1id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match from the beginning of the line (`^`) to `value=`

```
echo 'header: 123xxx   xxx   value=file1id' | sed 's/^.*value=/header: 321aaa   aaa   value=/'
header: 321aaa   aaa   value=file1id
```